# With Drupal 6 is there a line of php similar to 'drupal_set_header()' to set 'head_title'?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6

In Drupal 6 is there a line of php similar to 'drupal_set_header()' to set 'head_title' from within the body of a given page?

Comment: Just to be clear: what are you trying to achieve? Do you want to set the content of `<title>` tag by calling a function? Or something else? If so, what?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
drupal_set_title("Your title goes here....")
```

For more details : http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!path.inc/function/drupal_set_title/6